# Testing SignalR app with Web Performance Test gets error on connect

Tags: asp.net, testing, web, signalr, performance-testing

I have a SignalR web application, while i'm trying to test it with Microsoft's "Web Performance Test" everything works well until we get to the following signalR request:
"https://[Computer-name]/RMWebClient/signalr/connect"

then, the test hangs on that line and finally gets error (probably timeout).